# How do I embed and extract arbitrary data in a PDF?

Tags: node.js, pdf, puppeteer

I have some code that reads in JSON data, formats it into an HTML file, then exports the HTML file into a PDF using puppeteer. Simplified code:

```
    // Parse data
    const rawData = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'data.json')));
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData.toString());

    // Create HTML file
    const htmlContent = generateHtml(parsedData)
    const htmlPath = path.join(__dirname, 'report.html');
    fs.writeFileSync(htmlPath, htmlContent);

    // Load HTML file and export it as a PDF
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(`file://${htmlPath}`);
    await page.pdf({ path: path.join(__dirname, 'report.pdf') });
    await browser.close();
```

This PDF will be generated automatically and distributed to users who will be free to forward around.

For troubleshooting purposes, I would like to be able to embed the contents of `parsedData` into the PDF file. If I receive a bug report and they provide the PDF, it would convenient to be able to extract the underlying JSON data for inspection.

I've considered simply adding the JSON to the report as a text block but it's already at 20k characters and I anticipate that it will grow much more, making it a little unwieldy.

Is there a way to embed this data into the PDF in a way that makes it easy to extract later?

Comment: We use PDF File attachments for this. You could zip it also and attach the zip. Not sure they are supported with the PDF tool you are using.

Comment: @KevinBrown - Thank you. We ended up going with your suggestion by using the pdf-lib npm package. If you want, please create an answer and I will mark it as the accepted answer.